# 404 when navigating to a get route in laravel on production

Tags: laravel, nginx

On production, when I navigate to http://api.mywebsite.com/api/mail/send in my browser I get a 404 page not found even though my route is defined and "I think" i have my nginx configured correctly. Maybe someone can spot my problem?

in api.php I have this: Route::get('/api/mail/send', 'MailController@index');

Then in my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mywebsite.com I have the following defined:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mywebsite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin mywebsite.com;

}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.mywebsite.com;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin mywebsite.com;

        root /mywebsite/api/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php = 404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

The second server block is for my laravel api which I want on a subdomain as shown.
Is there anything wrong with my config?

Comment: Is this a new route? If so, did you clear the route cache?

Comment: it has existed for a while, but even just now cleared the route cache and still the same issue.

Comment: I just noticed in your route you declared`/api/` however routes in the `api.php` are already prefixed with `/api/`. So I think your route should be `api.mywebsite.com/api/api/mail/send`. Can you give that a try to see if the route resolves?

Comment: hmm still seems to cause the 404 even when I tried your suggested url. I feel like it has to do with not pointing at my laravel public folder correctly but it does look right